# How can I suppress parts of the date in a report

Tags: custom-reports

I am modifying the activity report for use in a dashlet.

The activity date ('civicm_activity_activity_date_time') is currently displayed as November 18th, 2015 2:00 PM

I can change the format of a date using CRM_UTILS_DATE::customFormat, but since this is a report of this current week's activities, what I really want to do is shorten it all by suppressing the month and the year altogether - (and even converting the date to a day)

Is there a CiviCRM way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would just revert to either to `DateTime()` or `date('D', strtotime($dateField))`

Comment: Thanks ErikH - so no CiviCRM way of doing things just write a php function to provide the desired string to display.